# Can an application started by a windows service connect to internet

Tags: python, windows, service, windows-services, windows-authentication

I have a script in python whose purpose is to make sure that a particular application that continuously download data from internet stays up all the time. If the application crashes, the script brings it back up.

Since the system is in Windows, I modified the script into a service, so that even if windows restarts itself, the service will ensure that the application is up even if the user is not logged in.

The service was installed using an account that has admin permissions. The system seems to work fine except that the application that is successfully brought up is not connecting to internet (The application writes log file, so we can be sure that it started fine). Faces the same issue if the user is changed to Network Service or Local System

So I was wondering if there are any permissions required to help it connect to internet (or is this not possible at all).

Comment: User accounts aren't just about permissions. They are also about environment. If you launch application X from a service running under a system account, the application will look for configuration data using that account's predefined locations.

Comment: @IInspectable, I am python's os.chdir to change the service's working directory to appropriate location before launching the application. This seems to be working fine. Otherwise the application would have either not started or would have crashed immediately after crash. So that should not be the issue.

Comment: The current working directory has no bearing on the ability of an application to start. A well-behaved application doesn't rely on the current working directory anyway. It has way more robust options to query its environment, like [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath). You should investigate, where application X stores its persistent data (e.g. the registry, known folder locations of the current profile, etc.).

Comment: @IInspectable, The application too is created by the team that I am in. They do take the config file from the current directory. And it is successfully taking the config file. Otherwise it will not have started successfully

Comment: If you control the code for this application, why don't you fix the bug(s) that cause the application to crash? At any rate, you're going to have to provide more info in the question, ideally a [mcve].

Comment: Application is a reliable old application. It didn't not crash. TCP communication just doesn't seem to work as if it is blocked (no data goes out or comes in). This application can be started without the script and runs fine. Even with the script it can be started and runs perfectly fine. The issue comes in when the script is modified to be a service and if such a service script starts the application. Note that once the application is started it needs no further input and hence the issue is not of input. The only option before me is permission issue and hence the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify an account that can run the application normally on the service's Log On tab (of the Services.msc control panel application):

[image]

Additional details in the [Windows Services FAQ](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService).